# Making android Translate animations as per screen width

Tags: android, image, animation

I wrote this code for an android Translate Animation on x axis -

```
ImageView myimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage);

Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 80, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(100);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
myimage.startAnimation(animation);
```

This image moves the same 80 units on all screen sizes.

Is there any way so that it moves a distance equal to 80% of the screen width ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just calculate it yourself:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float calculatedWidth = metrics.widthPixels * 0.8f;

Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, calculatedWidth, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(100);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: The image goes out of screen when using this way. Anything wrong with the code ? @user3249477

Comment: @Gissipi_453 `calculatedWidth -= imageWidth;`

Comment: Done now. I had committed a mistake. Thanks a lot.