# Android Translate animations as per screen width is not working properly?

Tags: android, animation

I am using translate animation on imageview , all are working properly but when i am testing my code on **Nexus5** , translate animation is taking same width for all supporting devices.

i tried this link code

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073335/making-android-translate-animations-as-per-screen-width)

here is my code

```
   animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f);  
    animation.setDuration(8000);  // animation duration 
    iv_progress.startAnimation(animation); 
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
```

i am confuse that where i am doing wrong,please help me,answer will be appriceted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `DisplayMetrics`?

Comment: @PiyushGupta ha piyush maine use kia tha usko par kuch nh hua..:(

Comment: @PiyushGupta ho gya...:)]

Comment: Yes. I have seen. I was telling to you about to get width from that...

Comment: @PiyushGupta wow..nice...kya hua piyush tumko....kisi b bt ka reply nh

Comment: Naah.. If i have something then i will not commented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75254/discussion-between-navya-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().width;
animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, width,
            0.0f, 0.0f);
```

By these lines you get your screen width programmatically and use it in your animation object.

Good luck there.

Comment: hope it solves your problem. Can you please debug and make sure width has proper value? If it is not we would try to get another way to get screen width. :/

Comment: thnks alot sir... you made my day...its working..properly..:)